# Setting a custom $query->query_vars['meta_key'] breaks the WordPress menu

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, pre-get-posts

First of all, my problem is very similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629245/wordpress-menu-disappears-when-query-query-varsmeta-key-is-set However, the answer accepted for this question does not help me for some reason.

I am using the following code in my functions.php file to filter posts based on a custom field, which is set in the URL of a page:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    // validate
    if( is_admin() )
    {
        return;
    }

    if( isset($_GET['county']) )
        {
            $query->set('meta_key', 'venue_county');
            $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['county']);
        }   
    }
    return;

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

I copied the code from this tutorial http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/

The above code works, in that it filters the results on the venues archive page, if county has been set in the URL. However, this then breaks the wordpress main navigation menu.

When I try and apply the fix to the code, by adding

```
if( ! $query->is_main_query()) return;
```

This fixes the menu but breaks the URL filtering, so all posts are returned not only those with a custom field of venue_county set to something.

It's very frustrating, any help would be most appreciated!

For example, is there a way of checking to see if the query is for the nav menu and not touching it if it is, but still allow modifying the second query of actually getting the posts on the page? I think this is what `if( ! $query->is_main_query()) return;` is supposed to do...

Thanks

Comment: is your query the main query, or is it a query you run in the template?

Comment: It is a query used on an archive page of a custom post type.

Comment: well that's why it doesn't work, it's not the main query. you're probably needlessly running an extra query in the template, but I'd have to see that code to confirm.

Comment: I'd love to make it more efficient, but I don't see how its needlessly running an extra query if I can't get it to work using the functions.php method... The code I'm using is: 'if( isset($_GET['county']) ) {

  $args = array_merge($wp_query->query, array(
   'orderby' => 'title',
   'order' => 'asc',
   'meta_query' => array(
     array(
      'key' => 'venue_county',
      'value' => $_GET['county'],
      'compare' => '='
     )
   )
  ));'

Comment: if you're running a query in the template, that's a query in addition to the main query, which runs before the template is loaded, regardless of whether or not you output the results from that query. remove the extra query and run the normal loop in your template, then your functions.php code will work. using `pre_get_posts` on the main query is more efficient, because it modifies the query before it is run, and won't require the extra query in the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The previous developer has coded the templates in such a way that he uses a few queries for an A-Z feature, so I think I'll just stick with what is working for now and use pre_get_posts in future. I have used it before on another project, but that was modifying the main query to only use a custom post type. Anyway, thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem on an archive page of a custom post type with a needless extra query; for pagination reasons. Searching for the same solution I found this post on Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303743/new-wp-query-or-pre-get-posts-to-view-all-posts-for-custom-post-type

I had a play and added this line of code into the function.

```
if( ! $query->is_post_type_archive()) return;
```

So my final code looks like this. I tested this and it doesn't seem to affect any other pages in any way and fixes the problem for me.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query )
{

    // validate
    if( is_admin() )
    {
        return $query;
    }

    if( ! $query->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    // allow the url to alter the query
    if( isset($_GET['status']) )
    {
        $query->set('meta_key', 'status');
        $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['status']);
    }

    // always return
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this working by using the if statement at the top of the archive template instead of inside functions.php. This may not be as efficient as including it in a functions.php file (2 queries, possibly?) but at least it works for me now.